# Toolbar location in TinyMCE 4

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

How I can to move toolbar to top in TinyMCE 4? I see this code:

```
theme : 'advanced',
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'top',
```

But it doesn't work in 4 version. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the online demo for TinyMCE you will see that in V4 the toolbar is already at the top:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/

Comment: its not inline editing...((( I must lift up this panel with inline editing.(((

Comment: Can you make a TinyMCE Fiddle so people can see what you are doing?  That will help people provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: Check out this Fiddle:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/krfaab/1

The menu bar appears above or below based on where the content is in the browser.  The first <div> the menu is below because its at the bottom of the window - the other two its at the top (its default).

Comment: my trouble in this fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/krfaab/2 If you scroll page to bottom and activate editor, toolbar will be located at the bottom under the text. I want to attach this to the top of the page.

Comment: Check out this API:  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#fixed_toolbar_container.  This will allow you to control where the toolbar is placed on the page.  Does that address your issue?